# Can anyone explain the error and/or provide some solutions of the uploaded logcat ss?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Android Studio Logcat]

I am trying to implement OTP verification in Android-Studio for my app. I am using Firebase's Realtime Database but when I click the 'OTP' button my app stops working. Can anyone explain the error ?

The code is -

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(customerGenerateOtp.this,"Generating OTP !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phone,90,TimeUnit.SECONDS,customerGenerateOtp.this,new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                Toast.makeText(customerGenerateOtp.this,"Verification success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(customerGenerateOtp.this,"Verification failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String pin, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(pin, forceResendingToken);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),customerGenerateOtp.class);
                                intent.putExtra("mobile",phone);
                                intent.putExtra("verificationId",pin);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(customerGenerateOtp.this,"Sorry! No account with " + phone + " exists.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Kindly, add the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share images of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: This is production build ? Did you set minifyEnabled = true in your build.gradle